# Tweaking \tilde{} command

Tags: math-mode

When one wants to typeset tilde over a character, one uses the `\tilde{}` command. Suppose I want to tweak that command so that it prints tilde and some additional character. How would I do that?

Ideally, I would like to know how `\tilde{}` is defined in TeX internals, but I do not know how to find it.

Edit based on comments below: The additional character should be in accent position as well. That is, next to the tilde.

Namely, I would like to produce something akin to the figure below, which is produced with the help of the `accents` package using `$\accentset{\sim i}{X}$`, except for the `\sim` replaced by tilde. (When I include tilde using `\textasciitilde` or `\texttildelow` the tilde is either too high or too low and the size of `i` is changed.)

[image]

Comment: According to texdef, `\tilde` is `\mathaccent "707E\relax`

Comment: It’s a macro defined in the LaTeX kernel: its definition is simply `\mathaccent "707E\relax`, and `\mathaccent` is a TeX primitive.

Comment: To see how a macro is defined, run `latex` without file name, enter `\relax` at the `**` prompt, and then `\show\tilde` at the `*` prompt. You will get the information that `\tilde` is a macro defined as `\mathaccent "707E\relax`. Or write `\show\tilde` into a text file and run latex on it.

Comment: More precisely, its definition can be found at line 412 of file `fontmath.ltx`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “printing tilde and some additional charater”.  What’s the rationale for doing so?  Why not to define a separate command, with a different name?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Maybe I was not clear enough. Ultimately, I want to define a new command. It should do what the `\tilde{}` command does, that is, print a tilde over a character, but put what I additionally define next to the tilde. Next to the tilde means at the same level.

Comment: Do you mean that this “something additional” should be in the accent position too?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Yes. I believe I should have used 'in accent position' to start with. I will edit the question.

Comment: I’m now logging out, but I think it would be helpful if you included a picture of the output you’d like to get; even a photo of a hand-made drawing will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\jan@xtilde@base}
\newsavebox{\jan@xtilde@top}
\newcommand{\xtilde}[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \tilde{#2}%
  \else
    {\jan@xtilde{#1}{#2}}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\jan@xtilde}[2]{%
  \sbox\jan@xtilde@top{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle#1$}%
  \sbox\jan@xtilde@base{$\m@th#2$}%
  \kern-.25\wd\jan@xtilde@top
  \tilde{%
    \kern.25\wd\jan@xtilde@top
    #2%
  }%
  \kern-.75\wd\jan@xtilde@top
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\jan@xtilde@base+\dp\jan@xtilde@top+1.5pt}{\copy\jan@xtilde@top}%
  \kern-.25\wd\jan@xtilde@top
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$X\xtilde{X}\xtilde[i]{X}X\xtilde[f]{X}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I’m really sorry, but I cannot (yet) upvote, for two reasons:  (1) Hard-coding a vertical gap of `+1.5pt` is out of question, what if the document is typeset at `12pt` or the formula occurs in a footnote?  (2) Try `\xtilde[i]{X}^{2}`, compare it with `\tilde{X}^{2}`, and recall Rule 12, sixth sentence (“If the nucleus is a single character, … between the new and old values of h(x).”).

Comment: I forgot to add a third reason: try `\xtilde[i]{xy^{2}}` for example.  The accented symbol is typeset in cramped style (again Rule 12, second sentence), so you should use `mathtools` and say `\sbox\jan@xtilde@base{$\m@th\cramped{#2}$}`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti All interesting comments, but in absence of examples from the OP, I'm not going to spend more time on this.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very nice solution. Gustavo's examples are interesting. After seeing what `\tilde{x^{2}}` produces I would not hold his third reason against your solution. However, `$\xtilde[i]{X}^{2}$` puts the exponent unnaturally high and I have no idea how to 'bring it back' (I understand what your code does but my knowledge of TeX is limited to be able to tweak it in order to get what I want).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\let\origtilde\tilde
\def\tilde#1{\origtilde{#1}Hello!}
$\tilde{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

After you edited the post I understood what you wanted.

This solution uses `accents` for the `\setaccent` command and `mathtools` for `\mathrlap` (I want the tilde to be centered on the character).  Also I used `\sim` rather than tilde since it looks better with added char

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,accents}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\sim\mathrlap{i}}{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not clear enough and I apologize for that. Your example works, but suppose I want to put 'i' next to the tilde in `\tilde{}`. That is, at the same level, in, say, double-subscript `\scriptscriptstyle` size.

Comment: It’s a bit embarassing to tell this to a user with a reputation like yours, but [you shouldn’t be using the `minimal` class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/69818), especially in an answer given to an unexperienced user.

Comment: Thanks.  I used minimal just to skip the line `\pagestyle{empty}`, and then use `pdfcrop` to get the mwe.

Comment: Thank you Boris. This is almost what I wanted. I managed to change the `\sim` to tilde (surprisingly tricky, I am still not sure which one I like better) by getting tilde via `\raisebox{0.075ex}{\texttildelow}`.