# hyperreferencing \hat, \tilde and other math accents

Tags: math-mode, hyperref

I am unsuccessfully trying to have variants of the macros:

```
\hat, \tilde, \check, \grave, ...
```

such that the accent is possibly clickable and gives a link to some other part of the document (using \hyperlink or \hyperref for instance). The math on which the accent occurs should not be affected (i.e not be a link). The display should also not be affected compared to the normal command (neither insider nor outside of the command).

There is the post [Tweaking \tilde{} command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357699/tweaking-tilde-command) with an answer of egreg which shows how to add symbols next to a tilde. However, it is not clear to me:

- how to adapt to the precise case I am describing, and,
- how much the technique leaves invariant the rest of the typesetting.

Comment: Can you add some more details about your problem? Just the accent should be clickable? I'm not sure why.

Comment: @egreg Yes, just the accent should be clickable. The idea is to go toward a fully hyperlinked document. Variables point to their moment of introduction. For instance, imagine that \tilde{g} represents some lifting of the function g in some ways. Then, when \tilde{f} is used, clicking on f would jump to the introduction of f, and clicking on the tilde symbol on top of it would jump to the definition of \tilde (i.e the definition of the lifting).